# EFCore 3.0 and usage of Group By

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am using EF Core 3.0 and I am facing a problem with Group By using Linq.
After searching, I came to know that as per design in EF Core 3.0 the Group By is not possible on the client side. Hence when using Group By EF throws an exception.

If client side Group By is not possible, then how to use the SQL Group By?

Can anyone could give an hint of to issue Group By on the server side (i.e. in the database server)?

```
var results = db.TransferJobs.Include(j => j.TransferObjects) 
    .Where(j => j.Status == JobStatus.Succeeded) 
    .GroupBy(j => j.LinkedJobIdentifier).ToList();
```

TransferJob is a simple objet having a list of TransferObjects.

Comment: We need to see the query. Often, when using navigation properties properly you don't even need `GroupBy`.

Comment: Group By *is* possible on the server side, that is, in the database. There are some limitations still, though. Please share your query. In general, you can group by a simple property and perform some grouping operation, like a sum or a count.

Comment: Hello,Here is the query :

`var results = db.TransferJobs.Include(j => j.TransferObjects)
                                             .Where(j => j.Status == JobStatus.Succeeded)
                                             .GroupBy(j => j.LinkedJobIdentifier).ToList();`

TransferJob is a simple objet having a list of TransferObjects.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, i have edited my questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In this case I'd do the grouping after `ToList`, i.e. do your own client-side grouping.